# How can I offset a range within a formula?

Tags: excel, range, formula, offset

I have a simple printout (Sheet X) that takes fields from another sheet (Sheet Y) and populates based on the values from Sheet Y. For instance, the top left corner of X takes from cell B5 on Y, while another field on A takes from E5 on Y. The result is a form that includes data from Y, presented more fashionably.

Sheet X is currently populated with data from Row 5. I want to create a macro that will take each field on Sheet X and move all ranges in the formulas down 2 rows, so that Sheet X is now populated with data from Row 7. Then I want to be able to hit the same button to move from Row 7 data to Row 9 data, and so on and so forth.

I've tried using offset, but my issue is with targeting the specific range within the formula, especially given that there are 2.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your attempted code so others can work around that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting the macro change each Offset() formula, let the Offset refer to a single cell and let the macro change the number in that cell.

[image]